# How to know about moment when user are logged?

Tags: javascript, jquery, logging, popup

I have such issue. I have webpage which sends request with specific paramters to third-party website and after request third-party sends response with code to redirectUrl (oAuth protocol of security and authentication). If you aren't logged in this third-party resource it redirects you to login page. I want to make this login process of authentication in pop up window. So workflow:
1. User press button to get code from third-party
2. If user not logged in third-party then pop up window appears with login on third-party side. Code is retrieved.
3.If user logged then pop up window appears and immediatly closes and retrieved code is printed on my web page.
My code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#popupButton').click(function() {
         signinWin = popupwindow("url",
                 "SignIn",960,630);
         signinWin.focus();
         signinWin.onload=function(){
            var code=getQueryVariable("code");
             if(code != null){
                signinWin.opener.location.reload(true); 
                signinWin.document.write("<script>this.close()<\/script>");
             } 
        }
    });
});

function popupwindow(url, title, w, h) {
      var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
      var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
      return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
} 

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
      var query = signinWin.location.search.substring(1);
      var vars = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
          return pair[1];
        }
      } 
}
```

It works good if I'm logged in. But when I'm not logged first appers loggin window and I don't know how to know about moment when user entered his login and what should I do then? Maybe I should use ajax??

Comment: you normally check the login status with OAuth token returned from the server and stored in the session storage of your browser

Comment: ajax is the best solution...